# Date Format Manipulation(YYYY/MM/DD-to-MM/DD/YYYY)

Tags: c++, vector, formatting, substring

Okay, so i use this stringstream technique in order to pull out objects from a .txt file the type, date, score, etc. and push it back into a vector later in my code.
My problem is that the date from the input file is in YYYY/MM/DD format, I need to switch it to MM/DD/YYYY, but am unfamiliar with how to do so. I've been told using a sub-string approach would work, but i am a newbie to C++, so does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem of mine?

```
void LineData :: Set_Line (const string s)
{
    stringstream temp (s);

    temp >> type;

    temp >> date;

    string max;
    temp >> max;
    max_score = atoi (max.c_str());

    string actual;
    temp >> actual;
    actual_score = atof (actual.c_str());

    ws(temp);
    getline(temp, name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways that it can be done:

```
//this will split-up the string
int i = 0;
stringstream ssdate(date); //date needs to be stringstream

while (getline(ssdate, part, '/'))
{
    if(i == 0) year = part;
    if(i == 1) month = part;
    if(i == 2) day = part;
    i++; //counter
}

//now all you have to do is arrage them how you need them
//If you want me to show you that I can
```